# How can I retrieve limited number of rows in table but search in all the database set?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a big database with hundred thousands rows, so I would like to make a server-side processing without using DataTables JQuery plugin (or others) to display my results. Down below my code example for a table:

```js
searchtable();
sortabletable();

function searchtable() {
  $("#searchtable").keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
      if (!index) return;
      $(this).find("td").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
        var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
        $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
        return not_found;
      });
    });
  });
}

function sortabletable() {
  $('.sortable').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this); // This sortable table
    var $tbody = $table.find('tbody'); // Store table body
    var $controls = $table.find('th'); // Store table headers
    var rows = $tbody.find('tr').toArray(); // Store array containing rows

    $controls.on('click', function() { // When user clicks on a header
      var $header = $(this); // Get the header
      var order = $header.data('sort'); // Get value of data-sort attribute
      var column; // Declare variable called column

      // If selected item has ascending or descending class, reverse contents
      if ($header.is('.ascending') || $header.is('.descending')) {
        $header.toggleClass('ascending descending'); // Toggle to other class
        $tbody.append(rows.reverse()); // Reverse the array
      } else { // Otherwise perform a sort                            
        $header.addClass('ascending'); // Add class to header
        // Remove asc or desc from all other headers
        $header.siblings().removeClass('ascending descending');
        if (compare.hasOwnProperty(order)) { // If compare object has method
          column = $controls.index(this); // Search for columnâ€™s index no

          rows.sort(function(a, b) { // Call sort() on rows array
            a = $(a).find('td').eq(column).text(); // Get text of column in row a
            b = $(b).find('td').eq(column).text(); // Get text of column in row b
            return compare[order](a, b); // Call compare method
          });

          $tbody.append(rows);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  
  var compare = { // Declare compare object
    name: function(a, b) { // Add a method called name
      a = a.replace(/^the /i, ''); // Remove The from start of parameter
      b = b.replace(/^the /i, ''); // Remove The from start of parameter

      if (a < b) { // If value a is less than value b
        return -1; // Return -1
      } else { // Otherwise
        return a > b ? 1 : 0; // If a is greater than b return 1 OR
      } // if they are the same return 0
    },
    duration: function(a, b) { // Add a method called duration
      a = a.split(':'); // Split the time at the colon
      b = b.split(':'); // Split the time at the colon

      a = Number(a[0]) * 60 + Number(a[1]); // Convert the time to seconds
      b = Number(b[0]) * 60 + Number(b[1]); // Convert the time to seconds

      return a - b; // Return a minus b
    },
    date: function(a, b) { // Add a method called date
      a = new Date(a); // New Date object to hold the date
      b = new Date(b); // New Date object to hold the date

      return a - b; // Return a minus b
    },
    nope: function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filterinplaylist" class="filter hidden-phone">
  <input type="text" id="searchtable" placeholder="Filter...">
</div>

<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sort="nope">id</th>
      <th data-sort="name">Artist</th>
      <th data-sort="name">Title</th>
      <th data-sort="name">Genre</th>
      <th data-sort="duration">Duration</th>
      <th data-sort="date">Release</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="ui-sortable">
    <tr data-track-id="320" id="track320" class="ui-sortable-handle">
      <td class="firstTD">
        <div data-tname="945970554_7695391_165206366.mp3" data-tid="1" id="play1" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="countlist1" class="countlpl" data-count-list="1">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>disgrap96</td>
      <td id="song-url1">
        <div id="song-name1">Hellberg - The Girl</div>
      </td>
      <td>Remix</td>
      <td>3:47</td>
      <td>2015-11-14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-track-id="318" id="track318" class="ui-sortable-handle">
      <td class="firstTD">
        <div data-tname="945970554_7695391_165206364.mp3" data-tid="18" id="play18" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="countlist1" class="countlpl" data-count-list="18">18</div>
      </td>
      <td>Simon Deoro</td>
      <td id="song-url1">
        <div id="song-name18">Love the way</div>
      </td>
      <td>Dance</td>
      <td>3:41</td>
      <td>2015-12-14</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

MySQL returns limited rows and I can easily make an Ajax POST to retrieve more `tr` objects but how can I do to filter and search inside the **entire database** and not only through the objects shown on page?

Comment: add your code in for loop to execute number of times

Comment: @RahulDambare I don't get it, my SQL retrieve X rows (eg. 20) and I want to search inside the entire database

Comment: Since you don't have all the data clientside, your `searchtable()` would not work. You need to search on serverside, i.e. implement an API to retrieve data by search term, make ajax call to it and update your table with results.

Comment: @AlexBlex in PHP is it correct to create a Json with `json_encode` and retrieve data making call to it?

Comment: I don't get the the part about *retrieve data making call to it*, but yes, [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) converts its first argument to a json string.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use angular.js and fetch all data and stored in json object.Then use paging to limit your data to show.When you search you should search on that json object.

Answer (score -1):

I believe answer to your problem will be changing a bit SQL statement and add field "limit" to it. Like

```
select `field(s)` from table where .... limit x
```

Where `x` is:

- "digit" number of results to return
- "digit1,digit2" where "digit1" is start number (for example on second page or second ajax request), "digit2" is same as "digit" - number of results to return in total.